# Is it okay if I support an English football team called "Newcastle United" since its crest has a flag containing the Saint George's cross?

Tags: halal-haram

I'm from Brunei and Islam is the official religion and I'm surely not the only one supporting that team, even our Sultan is fan of the team. I can't stop wondering and worrying whether it is okay if I support this team or not just because of that little cross on the flag on the very top of the crest? I really like the team a lot so I don't wanna leave them :( in the hadeeth it is known that prophet did not accept the cross that he remove it from every cloth picture or anything, and I wonder if that is applicable on this?

Comment: please look at this [http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/is-it-okay-if-i-have-the-barcelona-football-club-badge-hanging-on-my-wall-since]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t worry about it: you support their soccer team not a religious group. As long as you don’t go crazy over soccer or fight with other people over this team you are fine. It’s just a sport: don’t bring religion into it. Sports are made for fitness, so just enjoy it.

Secondly, it would be more wise to spend your time learning the Quran or the Hadith or even helping your mother or father, or even visiting the graves of your ancestors. These things are more respectable and kinder and, of course, without doubt will earn you rewards. Stop wasting your time on such trivial things: imagine if death grips you when you are sitting in front of the TV and watching a sport, while your soul could have been taken when you were praying. Death is an inevitable truth; don’t let it catch you at a time your soul would regret.