# Is it okay if I have the Barcelona Football Club Badge hanging on my wall since it has a Cross?

Tags: hadith, halal-haram

I asked this question before, but I want to make sure that it's okay because there are Hadiths which are against Crosses.

- > Al-Bukhaari narrated in his Saheeh from ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be
  >   pleased with her) that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be
  >   upon him) would never leave anything in his house on which there were
  >   any crosses without erasing them or – according to another report
  >   –cutting them out.

There is also a Hadith that mentions what one should do should he encounter a cross:

- > “Whoever among you sees an evil action (munkar), let him change it
  >   with his hand [by taking action], and if he cannot, then with his
  >   tongue [by speaking out], and if he cannot, then with his heart [by
  >   feeling that it is wrong], and that is the weakest of faith.”
  >   (Narrated by Muslim).
- > Muslim also narrated that Abu’l-Hayaaj al-Asadi said: “ ‘Ali (may
  >   Allaah be pleased with him) said to me: ‘Shall I not send you on the
  >   same mission that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of
  >   Allaah be upon him) sent me? Do not leave any image without blotting
  >   it out and do not leave any built-up grave without levelling it.’

Comment: Highly doubt that.

Comment: Good question. A similar question, how about the British and Swiss flags, since they too have crosses on them?

Comment: Okay, but it is still okay that I support them? and I thought we weren't allowed to have crosses because they can lead us to commit shirk and my Iman is strong so it wouldn't affect me.

Answer (score 2):

One time a Sheikh saw me wearing a Barcelona shirt and asked me to remove the cross from the logo because it is considered haram. You can either remove the logo completely or use a needle and thread to sew the cross and make it look like something else.

I would like to add an important note regarding the last two hadith. The only place where you can use force to change things is in your house. Other than that, only authorities or those who have the power (i.e: police or military) should use force to level graves or ask the public to enjoin good and leave the bad. This is clear from the hadith in which Prophet(commander) sent Ali(soldier) to do this. So please don't go around forcing people to remove Barcelona badges or go around graveyards leveling graves and causing chaos. Instead, give them Dawah and tell them about the haidhts. If they obeyed, then Alhamdolelah. If not, you have done your part by delivering the message.

Answer (score 1):

The cross symbol (+ symbol, not the dagger symbol †) is one of those misunderstood symbols that is highly religionised, but there is nothing religious about it.

It is a physics symbol, and its true meaning is to symbolise the energy that flows through the bloch wall of a magnet as depicted here ([link](http://www.overunity.com/5173/the-bloch-wall/dlattach/attach/61787/image//)).

That's where the free (additive) radiant energy comes and goes from a top to bottom 2D perspective of a magnet.

The Qur'an never talks about the cross symbol but it does talk about the dagger symbol,  verbalised as صلب (Sa la ba).

Comment: You really need to elaborate on why you think the FCBarcelona is symbolising the *energy that flows through the bloch wall of a magnet* in its crest, rather than (say) [St George's Cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_George%27s_Cross), commonly used as a symbol for Barcelona ([it's in their flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Barcelona)) as it represents [Saint George](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_George), the patron saint of Barcelona.

Comment: It's irrelevant whether the cross that St Georges refers to has anything to do with what barcelona is refering to, nor the cross that i refer to is what St Georges refers to.
What is important is the essence. Heck, maybe those who officialized the symbol used in barcelona didn't know the true meaning of it.
what's important is that we can associate some symbol with something real in physics rather than an abstract concept based on mere opinions of one or another..

Comment: وَمَا يَعْلَمُ تَأْوِيلَهُ إِلَّا اللَّـهُ ۗ وَالرَّ‌اسِخُونَ فِي الْعِلْمِ يَقُولُونَ آمَنَّا بِهِ كُلٌّ مِّنْ عِندِ رَ‌بِّنَا
but none save God knows its final meaning.Hence, those who are deeply rooted in knowledge say: "We believe in it; the whole [of the divine writ] is from our Sustainer
(3:7)
symbols, verses, physical phenomenons they all have meaning and how to interpret it, those who know the interpretation only can tell as much.. it's just a guide for us so that we don't go astray too far from the righteous/correct/WINNING path